# Import current Hexo blog to new PC

Tags: hexo

I started a Hexo blog on my laptop but I'd like to work on the same blog and update it on a different PC, how do I do this?

The blog is hosted via Github Pages on a public Git Repository. And I'm using Windows 10.

The blog doesn't use anything else asides from SASS (CSS), typical Hexo tools and the Git deployer for Hexo.

Thankyou.

**Question re-phrased**: how do I get a blog which has already been deployed (using Git + Git Pages) and bring it's code and it's content to a computer which doesn't have the blog's data, but has Git, Node and Hexo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hexo-git-deployer](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-deployer-git) to upload your blog and your sources

With this config

```
# _config.yaml
deploy:
  - type: git
    repo: git@github.com:<username>/<username>.github.io.git
    branch: master
  - type: git
    repo: git@github.com:<username>/<username>.github.io.git
    branch: src
    extend_dirs: /
    ignore_hidden: false
    ignore_pattern:
        public: .
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but there may be a communication problem regarding the question, what I was asking was, how do I get a blog which has already been deployed (using Git + Git Pages) and bring it's code and it's content to a computer which doesn't have the blog's data, but has Git, Node and Hexo?

Comment: You can't if you never upload source anywhere, there already generated on html, but i explained how to upload site and src at the same time so you can bring back your blog from anywhere

Comment: Aren't Git Page websites stored as repositories on Github, can't I use that repository...?

Comment: Your post in markdown are already translated into html with your theme, there no way to reverse that without the source, and with default option, only the generated content is uploaded on Github

Comment: So just to clarify, I can't recover the theme's files (JS, CSS, HTML), and I can't recover the public post files (posts)?

Comment: Like a compilated program, you can't recover if you didn't keep the source files, that why you should upload your src file with theme and `_config.yml` on another branch or sonewhere esle , for your case you could copy paste the text and make your md again